# Ternary operator

Tags: ruby, conditional-operator

I have an array `d = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, and want to put its elements together into a string delimited by `,` and *`and`*  at the last element so that it will become `foo, bar and baz`.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
s = ''
d.each_with_index { |x,i|
  s << x
  s << i < d.length - 1? i == d.length - 2 ? ' and ' : ', ' : ''
}
```

but the interpreter gives an error:

`` `<': comparison of String with 2 failed (ArgumentError) ``

However, it works with `+=` instead of `<<`, but the Ruby Cookbook says that:

> If efficiency is important to you, don't build a new string when you can append items onto an existing string. [And so on]... Use *`str << var1 << ' ' << var2`* instead.

**Is it possible without `+=` in this case?**

Also, there has to be a more elegant way of doing this than the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing some parenthesis:

```
    d = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    s = ''
    d.each_with_index { |x,i|
      s << x
      s << (i < d.length - 1? (i == d.length - 2 ? ' and ' : ', ') : '')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But why do I need the parenthesis with `<<` and not with `+=`?

Comment: << isn't a real operator, it's a method. += isn't a method, it's syntax sugar. They have different precedence rules.

Answer (score 4):

I'd find

```
s << i < d.length - 1? i == d.length - 2 ? ' and ' : ', ' : ''
```

hard to read or maintain.

I'd probably change it to

```
join = case
when i < d.length - 2 then ", "
when i == d.length - 2 then " and "
when i == d.length then ""
end
s << join
```

Or possibly do

```
earlier_elements = d[0..-2].join(", ")
s = [earlier_elements, d[-1..-1]].join(" and ")
```

Or

```
joins = [", "] * (d.length - 2) + [" and "]
s = d.zip(joins).map(&:join).join
```

Answer (score 1):

So much simpler like this:

```
"#{d[0...-1].join(", ")} and #{d.last}"
```